# Modeling PhoneGap apps with UML?

Tags: jquery, html, cordova, uml

I'm new to UML, but I think I grasp it conceptually. I'm also new to PhoneGap, jQuery, and HTML5 - planning on using those together, somehow, for mobile app development - been looking at appMobi for that.

I'm a little stumped by the verbose nature of the source code for the appMobil tutorial; though that was what was installed with the first appMobi PhoneGap XDK project I created. Long story short, I wonder if there's any way to model PhoneGap apps with UML?

I suppose that could involve modeling jQuery and HTML5 elements, as well as more general application elements. I really don't expect there's anything for it, yet, but I thought it might be useful to ask, at least - thanks, and cheers.

Comment: UML is just a langage , so you can model anything you want with that. The problem is to translate your model in javascript. In a paradigm where everything is dynamic there is no one to one relationship between the uml "model" and the code.

Comment: There's [Acceleo](http://www.eclipse.org/acceleo/) for that - will keep it in mind. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is to model a higher-level view of the system where instead of using HTML and jQuery specific concepts you use more generic ones like page, navigation, link,...

The OMG has recently issued a request for proposals for such a language. Check: http://www.ifml.org/

Comment: Brilliant! If I can take up a more abstract view of an app's interface, that should really help to make sense of it, indeed - might help with regards to portability, too. Thanks!